AD GPO with user settings only applied when explicitly moving user to OU
I have the following forest:
- spatiebas.internal
  - spatiebas
    - linux
    - windows

I created a GPO "windows logon scripts policy" (which only sets a login script in the user configuration), and linked it in the "windows" OU.

In active directory users and computers, I added one VM to this OU. When I start the VM and run gpupdate /force & gpresult /r, it doesn't show the GPO being applied to the user settings.
The only way I found to fix this, is by moving the my user account into the same OU. But, I don't want that, because that would mean my user account become windows/linux specific.
I also created an active directory group "windows-users" which contains all user accounts that should be able to logon to windows devices. Not that I would be very happy with that workaround, but it doesn't work either...
It must be possible to create GPO's for specific AD groups? Or even stronger, it must be possible to make GPOs for specific OU's that simply are set for every logged in user.
Am I missing the obvious here?
For clarity, this doesn't apply the GPO when I run gpupdate /force & gpresult /r

This does work, but is not acceptable because I can't create the limitation of a user account to either windows / linux OS


are set for every logged in user. that's what loopback policy processing does.

What you're describing is precisely what and how GPOs are supposed to work out of the box.  User settings apply to user accounts in the OU/path where the GPO is linked.  Computer settings apply to computer accounts in the OU/path where the GPO is linked.
First, create an OU for the user accounts, no reason they should remain in the default container.
Second, link the policy to the OU containing the users.  If a GPO contains user settings, it should be linked to an OU or parent OU of the user object.  If a GPO contains computer settings, it should be linked to an OU or parent of the computer object.
GPOs do not apply to groups, ever.  You can use Groups to filter the policies, but you cannot directly target a security group.
Yes, you could use loopback policy processing to ensure that every user logged onto a particular machine receives the same settings.  Loopback policy process certainly has it use case, but I would look to using that method only after using a user-based policy is insufficient.

Alright, this explains at least a part of where my brain took the wrong turn. Going to experiment a bit more with your input. Thanks. Will get back to this (hopefully, when I get any further...)

Loopback is the key. I think in my case, the only one. It works. Thanks for the pointer!
